# wrapping up html elements like capturing (border at corners) using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

i wanted to elements being wrapped with some outline (like capturing), whenever hovering it and it (outline) should remove when mouseout from it,  I tried something see the code below

```
function getFocussed(obj) {
            var $obj = $(obj);
            var wr1 = $('<div class="ad-wr1"></div>');
            var wr2 = $('<div class="ad-wr2"></div>');

            var width = parseInt($obj.css('width'));
            var height = parseInt($obj.css('height'));

            $(wr1).css('width', width + 12);
            $(wr2).css('width', width + 16);

            $(wr1).css('height', height + 12);
            $(wr2).css('height', height + 14);

            $obj.wrap(wr1).wrap(wr2);
        }    

function getUnFocussed(obj) {
        $(obj).parent().unwrap();
        $(obj).unwrap();
    }
```

now i am calling these functions to get focused and unfocused.

```
$('input[type="text"], div').hover(function () {
                if(!ad_focused) {
                    ad_focused = true;
                    getFocussed($(this));
                }
            }, function() {
                if(ad_focused) {
                    getUnFocussed($(this));
                    ad_focused = false;
                }
            });
        });
```

on below html elements

```
<input style="width: 300px; height: 20px;" class="txt" type="text" />
```

Its working fine     (see http://jsfiddle.net/ashokdamani/8ppc5pq0/1/) !,
But its affacting the other elements when focused or its nor working correctly with some margin property (in style)      (see http://jsfiddle.net/ashokdamani/8ppc5pq0/2/).
I know here are some css issues, but i am not able to fix, can anyone help ?

Basically i want whenever any element focused its get wrapped by outlines on its corners without disturbing the layout or other elements. Thank you

Comment: If you want, this is one way of achieving your goal, assuming your background-color is consistent and not an image or gradient: http://jsfiddle.net/tlaverdure/NrU34/ otherwise, easiest way would be to create a background image in photoshop or another program that looks exactly how you wish, and to add a `background-image:url("");` on `:focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, are you requesting a solution for hovering (mouseover) or for focus? especially on input fields - these are two separate things - you can have the focus in your input field, and the mouse over another.

i like your idea, of creating two overlays, one white with rounded corners, and one black, to create the desired effect.
but i don't like to create elements within js, so i just manipulated the css properties.

i tried to find a solution, that can be applied to every element of a page - at least the hover effect. the focus will only apply to focusable elements (like input fields)

i wrapped everything inside my own content container. to have the z-index working, you need to have the 'to hover' elements on the same nodelevel like the hover-overlays:

```
<div class="contentContainer">
    <input class="inputText focusable" name="myName" type="text" />
    <input class="inputText focusable" name="myData" type="text" />
    <div class="hoverDark"></div>
    <div class="hoverLight"></div>
    <div class="focusDark"></div>
    <div class="focusLight"></div>
</div>
```

the class 'focusable' won't get any .css markups. it's only used to select those elements via js, that should get the overlay effect.
since there can be up to two overlay effects - one focus and one mouseover, i need four divs.

next we get the css markup. for the input fields, i chose the position: relative. so i don't need to position every field with it's own unique absolute pos. and to have the z-index working, position has to be something else then static! the overlay-divs have some properties, that don't change. these are pinned down in the css also.

```
.inputText {
    position: relative; 
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.hoverDark, .hoverLight, .focusDark, .focusLight {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
.hoverDark {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.focusDark {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.hoverLight, .focusLight {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

you'll miss the top/left and width/heigt for the overlays. they are set via js. this way, you can use the effect on a complete form, over textareas, radio buttons and so on...

finally, the js. first i started with hiding the overlay divs, to avoid a black 1px dot on the page. unfortunately, .show() won't work, if you set the visibility to hidden via css. so the first four lines are needed.

```
    $(".hoverDark").hide();
    $(".hoverLight").hide();
    $(".focusDark").hide();
    $(".focusLight").hide();
```

next we bind the mouseover handler to all elements, with the class 'focusable'.
[.hover()]/http://api.jquery.com/hover/) can be used to define the mousein and mouseout event within itself, that's why it's used here. first function, of course, is for the mousein handler.
we start with getting the hovered elements dimensions (including margins, paddings and borders) and position. since position always starts at 0, we have to substract 1px to define the target position of our overlay, to center the hovered element correct.

```
$(".focusable").hover(function () {
    var elemOuterWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    var elemOuterHeight = $(this).outerHeight(true);
    var elemPos = $(this).position();
    var elemPosTop = elemPos.top - 1;
    var elemPosLeft = elemPos.left - 1;
```

with those variables set, we apply position, width and height to our hover overlays

```
    $(".hoverDark").css({
        "width": elemOuterWidth,
            "height": elemOuterHeight,
            "top": elemPosTop,
            "left": elemPosLeft
    });

    $(".hoverLight").css({
        "width": elemOuterWidth,
            "height": elemOuterHeight,
            "top": elemPosTop,
            "left": elemPosLeft
    });
```

quite simple, isn't it?
all we need to do now, is show our overlays. the .stop() is used to prevent flickering while moving the mouse over our focusable area.

```
    $(".hoverDark").stop(true, true).show();
    $(".hoverLight").stop(true, true).show();
```

that's all. oh no... i forget, we need the mouseout handler. well that's a nobrainer:

```
}, function () {
    $(".hoverDark").stop(true, true).hide();
    $(".hoverLight").stop(true, true).hide();
});
```

i don't really know, if the stop is needed here, just did copy and paste and it did work. after all, it's 3 am in my country right now, and i'm getting lazy and tired...

the focusin/focusout functions are basically the same, to hover - only using my focusDark, focusLight divs, instead of the hovers...

see it in action, over here: http://jsfiddle.net/nmkr0k6o/4/
mouseover for a grey overlay, click into the field for a black one...

Comment: what if the element have some margin around it like http://jsfiddle.net/ashokdamani/nmkr0k6o/16/ ?

Comment: sry for the missing answer. have been on holidays in a region, with no mobile network. ctwheels already posted the easiest solution - just wrap the content in another container, and apply the margin to the outer container. if you don't like all those wrapping methods, resize elemOuterWidth and elemOuterHeight, by substracting the margins (get them with .css("margin-left") and so on) and reposition the overlay, by adding the top and the left margin to elemPosTop and elemPosLeft ...
but i'd recommend the wrapper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I have created a fiddle with what I believe is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/x3dxhbte/

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="absolute">
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="inputPadding"></div>
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="absolute">
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outerContainer {
    position:relative;
}
.container {
    padding:5px;
}
.absolute {
    position:absolute;
}
.inputPadding{
    height:35px; /*height of input + container padding + wanted padding*/ /*In this case(35px):input height = 20px, container padding=5px; wanted space between inputs is 10px*/
}
.outer:before, .outer:after, .inner:before, .inner:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:10%;
    width:10%;
}
.outer:after {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
}
.outer:before {
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
}
.inner:before {
    bottom:0;
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
.inner:after {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border-right: 3px solid black;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("input").focus(function () {
    var outer = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var inner = $(this).parent().parent();
    outer.addClass("outer");
    inner.addClass("inner");
});

$("input").focusout(function () {
    $(".outer").removeClass("outer");
    $(".inner").removeClass("inner");
});
```

Comment: well i wanted it on hover, but its great !, Thank you

Comment: Here, I've added a fiddle with the hover effect too, you can add and remove hover or focus or add other if you'd like, just copy the code for the focus and focusout events and paste them with a different event and copy the classes too (change or add number at end to make new class), change the border attributes to what you'd like. Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/x3dxhbte/1/

Comment: what if the element have some margin around it like jsfiddle.net/ashokdamani/nmkr0k6o/16 ? –

Comment: In that case wrap it in another div and give that div a margin (or padding) like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nmkr0k6o/17/